# Meeting ValueError while using flopy to load a MODFLOW-USG model

Tags: python, flopy

I am using FloPy to load an existing MODFLOW-USG model.

```
load_model = flopy.modflow.Modflow.load('HTHModel',model_ws='model_ws',version='mfusg',exe_name='exe_name',
                           verbose = True, check = False)
```

In the process of loading the LPF package, python shows that hk and hani have been successfully loaded, and then the following error is reported：

```
loading bas6 package file...
adding Package:  BAS6
   BAS6 package load...success
loading lpf package file...
   loading IBCFCB, HDRY, NPLPF...
   loading LAYTYP...
   loading LAYAVG...
   loading CHANI...
   loading LAYVKA...
   loading LAYWET...
   loading hk layer   1...
   loading hani layer   1...

D:\Anaconda\program\lib\site-packages\flopy\utils\util_array.py in parse_control_record(line, 
current_unit, dtype, ext_unit_dict, array_format)
    3215             locat = int(line[0:10].strip())

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-877.0
```

How can I solve this kind of problem.

By the way, I created this model by using the"save native text copy" function in GMS. Flopy can read other contents in the LPF package normally, and the position where it reports the error appears in the part of reading the [ANGLEX(NJAG)] data.

I compared the LFP file with the input and output description of MODFLOW-USG, and it meets the format requirements of the input file.

I am a newbie to pyhton and flopy and this question confused me a lot. Thank you very much for providing me with some reference information, whether it is about Python, FloPy, MODFLOW-USG or GMS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload your lpf file? Then I can check this out. But at first glance, that "'" before the -877.0 looks suspect - is that in the lpf file?